# How to find $\lim_{x\to 1^-} {f(x) - f(1) \over x-1}$ where $f(x) = x^2 + x + \sin\left({{1\over 2}\pi x}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to find $\lim_{x\to 1^-} {f(x) - f(1) \over x-1}$ where $f(x) = x^2 + x + \sin\left({{1\over 2}\pi x}\right)$?

What I have tried:

= $\lim_{x\to 1^=}$ ${x^2+x+\sin\left({{1\over 2}\pi x}\right) - 3} \over (x-1)$

And I'm stuck here. I can't seem to simplify this expression to become $2x + 1 + {\pi\cos\left({{\frac12}\pi x}\right)\over 2}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

That limit is just $\;f'(1)\;$ ...(why?)

Comment: Is it possible to assume that the limit exists by doing the above?

Comment: @WeitingChen Yes indeed. The function $\;f\;$ is a sum of everywhere differentiable functions and thus differentiable itself. That means the limit defining the limit at each point exists and, thus, also the left and right limits in every point.

Answer (score 0):

Note, using [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), that $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}\frac{x^{2}+x+\sin\left(\pi x/2\right)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}\frac{2x+1+\pi\cos\left(\pi x/2\right)/2}{1}=\color{red}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

*Just another way to do it.*

To make life easier, change variable $x=y+1$ which makes
$$A=\frac{x^2+x+\sin\left({{\pi\over 2} x}\right) - 3} {x-1}=\frac{y^2+3 y+\cos \left(\frac{\pi  }{2}y\right)-1}{y}$$ Now, use, around $t=0$, the classical Taylor expansion $$\cos(t)=1-\frac{t^2}{2}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ which, replacing $t$ by $\frac{\pi  }{2}y$, gives $$\cos \left(\frac{\pi  }{2}y\right)=1-\frac{\pi ^2 }{8}y^2+O\left(y^4\right)$$ Replacing in $A$ $$A=\frac{3 y+\left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{8}\right) y^2+O\left(y^4\right)}{y}=3+\left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{8}\right) y+O\left(y^3\right)$$ which shows the limit but also how it is approached.